# Add Prototype Method on all Variables

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype

**Is it possible to add a Method to all Javascript Prototypes (*Object,array,function,string,number,boolean*)?**

Just for Example.
If i would like to add a new Prototype getter, which returns the Type of the Variable, the create Timestamp or something else, how could I do that?

For Information: It's not about what this function does!

**Edit:**

I would like to access the Function like every other Prototypen Function:

```
myVariable.myMethod(myParam)
```

Comment: `Object.prototype.myMagicMethod = function () { ... }`?

Comment: "create Timestamp" - you mean time of variable creation?

Comment: That was just an Example.

Comment: I would like to Access the Function like every other Prototypen Method (variable.myMethod(someParam))

Comment: "*which returns the Type of the Variable*" Are you looking for [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)?

Comment: Its not about what the function does. I want to know how to add any Function on every Prototype...If I want to know the Variable Type, I would use "typeof"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every JavaScript variable is either an object, or it auto-boxes to an object (like string, boolean and number), or it is null or undefined explicitly.

So, it seems like if you want to add a method to all those, you can add a function to Object.prototype which they all extend like Bar suggested.

```
Object.prototype.myMagic = function(){
    console.log("Hello");
};
"thisString".myMagic();
15.13.myMagic();
([]).myMagic();
```

Note that you are in fact not adding a function to the prototype of a string since a string is a primitive value and doesn't have a prototype, rather, you're adding a method to the prototype of Object - and strings "box" to `String` instances (which *are* objects) that extend `Object` and will have this method.

Also note that on ES5 systems, it's possible to create objects that do *not* extend `Object.prototype` via `Object.create(null)`, in ES6 it's also possible to modify the prototype of objects via `setPrototypeOf` or `__proto__`. However, outside those edge cases it should work.

Comment: @TimRücker however please do not really do this. There are very good reasons _not_ to extend `Object.prototype` yourself, this can cause a lot of problems when working with libraries and such.

Answer (score 3):

You can add it to `Object.prototype`.  All other prototype instances extend `Object.prototype`, and will inherit it from there.

```
Object.prototype.myMethod=function() {
   // ... whatever
};
```

Please note that extending built-in prototypes is not a recommended practice for "real-world" code.